# django admin list custom button's click event

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, custom-action

- admin.py

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/common.js',
        )

    list_display = ['custom_actions']

    def custom_actions(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(
            '<a class="button call_alert" href="#" data-msg="A">A</a>&nbsp;'
            '<a class="button call_alert" href="#" data-msg="B">B</a>'
        )
    custom_actions.short_description = 'Custom Actions'

admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

- js/common.js

```
(function($) {
    $(".call_alert").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).data("msg"));  // ★★★ Dose not!!! ★★★
    });
})($);
```

error message :

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at common.js:2
>       at common.js:5

How can I get alert message?

Is it impossible?

Please help..

Comment: You got error in your js code. You are doing fine in `admin.py`

Comment: @Glyphack Thank you for your advice. Would you tell me about that more?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've got it. :)

The script was changed like below.

```
if(!$) $ = django.jQuery;
$(function(){
    $(".call_alert").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).data("msg"));
    });
});
```

Thank you for all. :D